# Qual a melhor forma de criar uma árvore binária em linguagem C?

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, árvore

Sendo  uma árvore binária  um conjunto de registros que satisfaz certas condições. 
Gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de implementar uma árvore de busca binária em linguagem `C` seria usando uma estrutura com cabeça ou sem cabeça? 
 Não levando em consideração o seu modo de varredura `e-r-d` , `r-e-d`  ... 
Sei que o  endereço de uma árvore binária é o endereço de sua raiz e assim sendo como devo proceder?

Comment: E a sua dúvida é se é viável o uso dessa estrutura ou não?

Comment: DaviAragao Qual seria a melhor forma de usar essa estrutura, com ou sem cabeça. Gostaria de saber a diferença de desempenho entre ambas

Comment: A melhor forma no caso em que você apresentou é criar um ponteiro para raiz, que só vai servir pra apontar mesmo, assim vai ficar fácil balancear a arvore em caso de inserções posteriores.
É bom que saiba trabalhar com os ponteiros, já que vai mexer com ponteiro de ponteiro.
Respondido?

Comment: Cristopher Vidal Machado ,a parte de manusear ponteiros eu já entendo!!  Mas nesse caso devo criar uma  "cabeça" para a árvore ou trabalhar  diretamente com a estrutura sem uma cabeça?Valeu cara, obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem alguns fatores que podem interferir no desempenho de ambos os casos. A forma de implementação e qual é o conteúdo dessa "cabeça" podem interferir na análise do desempenho dos dois métodos de criação de uma árvore binária. Toda árvore precisa ter sua raiz apontada para que não se perca na memória, mas não necessariamente por uma "cabeça". Levando em consideração uma mesma implementação para ambos os casos, a árvore que não tem "cabeça" vai ser acessada em um tempo menor, já que tem um nó a menos no meio do caminho para o acesso. A diferença de desempenho no acesso será o tempo de acesso a um nó. Essa diferença, apesar de existir quase não será notada, o acesso é muito rápido.

Comment: O conteúdo dessa cabeça poderia ser uma variável que indica do número de elementos da árvore binária ! Obrigado DaviAragao

Comment: Mas veja que nesse caso uma variável, que não seja a cabeça da árvore seria mais vantajoso, pois não há a necessidade de ter que navegar todas as vezes por essa cabeça só para incrementar essa variável.